# View controller based rotation stop working when run the project on ios 13using xcode11

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios13

I Just installed the xcode 11 gm seed and i run my project on it and i realize that non of the rotation method called which were calling perfectly in xcode 10 and before. I don't know is it the bug with xcode or i missing something. Here are device rotation methods i am using

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{

    if([videoOptions[@"doc_type"] integerValue] == 3){
                return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
       if([videoOptions[@"doc_type"] integerValue] == 3){
            return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
        }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait|UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft|UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
    //    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if([videoOptions[@"doc_type"] integerValue] == 3){
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    //    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

// Notifies when rotation begins, reaches halfway point and ends.
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    //    NSLog(@"%ld, duration: %f", (long)toInterfaceOrientation, duration);
    //    [self.movieSlider hidePopover];
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{

    [self viewRotationCompleted];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both methods

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation 
                                duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation;
```

are depricated as of iOS8. You need to use their replacement method,

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size 
       withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator;
```

But this method won't be called for UPSideDown rotation. So You need to take care of that.